# Copy/paste a cell in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

This is got a be one of the most or the most silly question in all stack overflow!  But how do you copy/paste a cell in a COLABORATORY notebook?  There is a "copy cell" option, but not "paste cell" option.  Whenever I try to paste there's this pop message "Use cmd +V to paste", but there is no paste at all!.  In Jupyter is just "c" to copy and "v" to paste!  This is one of the reasons I do not use COLAB at all.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Copy/paste does work in Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari!

Comment: download chrome then to use Colab :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `ctrl` + `V` works for pasting on Google Colab in 2021 if you are using Chrome or Edge.

For Copying I use the Edit menu:

[image]

Alternatively you can use the context menu for copying:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do without mouse...?

Comment: @LouisYang as far as I can tell copying does not work without the mouse, but pasting works with CTRL + V

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to change your Colab Keyboard shortcuts by

1. Navigate to Tools > Keyboard shortcuts
2. Assign:

   - "Copy cell or selection" to `Cmd/Ctrl+M C` (press `Cmd/Ctrl+M` then `C`)
   - "Cut cell or selection" to `Cmd/Ctrl+M X`
   - "Delete cell/selection" to `Cmd/Ctrl+M D`

Then you can press `Cmd/Ctrl+M` then `C`, `X`, or `D` to copy, cut, or delete a cell. This is not as good as the original jupyter notebook method but at least you can do it with just keyboard.
[image]
[image: keyboard preferences]